# How to configure live555 framework for iphone app development?

Tags: iphone, rtsp, live555

I have the live555 framework with me. How to use it in Xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you haven't managed to configure it yet.

Try this command in the terminal in live555 folder

make iphoneos

It will generate the static libraries for you.

Comment: Thank you! Your idea triggered me another way ,by adding it as a static library from the dropcam source code. But still in need of an ignition to use the classes of the library.

Comment: The sample programs should be good enough of a starting point in testprogs folder of live555. Granted you will end up subclassing for your purposes.