# H.264 over RTP/RTSP (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, h.264, rtp

Is it possible to view video stream (H.264 live feed) over RTP/RTSP in iPhone natively? If not, is it possible to write an application for this purpose?

Answer (score 6):

Sure it is possible, in fact others have done it already, see e.g. [IPVision from TTrix](http://www.ttrix.com/apple/iphone/ipvision/ipvision.html).

Seems that [the Live555 libraries](http://www.live555.com/) can be compiled for iOS. See this SO question:

- [How to configure live555 framework for iphone app devleopment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191819/how-to-configure-live555-framework-for-iphone-app-devleopment)

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is possible now. 
Previously, RTSP is not allowed in AppStore, though someone migrated VLC to iPhone, but that app is removed from AppStore, you can only install it via jailbreak.
Now Apple doesn't insist this rule any more, so you can write RTSP player on iPhone as you will.
In face, I've done this a few months ago, migrating ffmpeg & live555 to iOS and make an app, absolutely feasible!

Comment: Where did you read that the rules have changed? Hasn't there been some official notice? Why hasn't VLC been re-submitted to the app store?

Comment: I didn't read any official notice, but, I've seen more and more apps with rtsp support in app store.

Comment: can you describe how you migrated to ffmpeg and live 555 to IOS in coding? Thanks in advance

Comment: hi Ciphor, can you please share the info about how you wrote the rtsp player? I'm looking for the info everywhere with no luck. Any tutorial you can suggest?