# iOS RTP live audio receiving

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, rtp, live-streaming

I'm trying to receive a live RTP audio stream in my iPhone but I don't know how to start. I'm seeking some samples but I can't find them anywhere.

I have a Windows desktop app which captures audio from the selected audio interface and streams it as µ-law or a-law. This app works as an audio server that serves any incoming connection with that streaming. I have to say that I've developed an Android app that receives that stream and it works, so I want to replicate this functionality on iOS. In Android we have "android.net.rtp" package to manage this and transmit or receive data streams over the network.

Is there any kind of equivalent package for iOS to implement this? Could you give me any kind of reference / sample to do this, or just tell me where to start?

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/7468056/22147 ?

Comment: Hmm but I was wondering if it's possible via audio toolbox framework or something like that. Isn't Live555 a third party open source player?

Comment: Aditionally, it says here http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/faq.html that I can´t use Live555 code in an iOS app that's distributed through Apple's 'App Store'.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this library[HTTPLiveStreaming](https://github.com/whiteblue3/HTTPLiveStreaming/tree/master/HTTPLiveStreaming), But his protocol maybe is not standard one, You can check my fork [aelam/HTTPLiveStreaming-1](https://github.com/aelam/HTTPLiveStreaming-1), I'm still working on it, it can be played by ffplay. You can try
check the file rtp.c in ffmpeg, I think it will help out