# creating app for playing RTSP streaming videos

Tags: iphone, ios, rtsp, live555, rtsp-client

I want to create a app which plays RTSP streaming video. I found lots of questions regarding to the same on SO. Every question has pointed me to [live555](http://www.live555.com). I followed the link and downloaded the c++ library. I wasn't able to build this at first and I got help from SO again and I implemented the solutions provided.

The process I'd followed till now is:

- In terminal I choose the path of my library and than `cd live` where my all files of the library placed.
- typed `./genMakefiles iphoneos` to terminal No error or success response from terminal
- after the upper command when I used `make` error occuers `-bash: make: command not found`
- When I used `./genMakefiles iphoneos make` response is `Usage: genMakeFiles <os-platform>`

I am not able to figured it out that how can I get that the library is build successfully or not? If Yes how to use it in ios app?

Which are the classes we need to access and create instance?

If library is not build how can I build it? and same how can I use it from the build location.

I tried following links

- [Live555 compile for iOS build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369933/live555-compile-for-ios-build-error)
- [H.264 over RTP/RTSP (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691147/h-264-over-rtp-rtsp-iphone)
- [How to configure live555 framework for iphone app devleopment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191819/how-to-configure-live555-framework-for-iphone-app-devleopment)

Thanks

Comment: hello, maybe your project was successful..
I am searching the web for circa 5 hours now trying to find a solution to view an H.264 RTSP Video only stream on the iPhone.
If you successfully managed to build your program and receive a stream, would you mind sharing your source code or sending me the weblinks to pages where you found tutorials?
You would be a savior in my pain, thank you

Comment: Sorry, but I wasn't able to finish that due to lack of helpful resources on google and stack. :( I didn't got any solution.

Comment: Is at least something working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually not, no one else reported it. However that framework SHOULD be in the search path if its not. Sorry about that

Comment: I was trying to build this for simulator that's why I got the problem. Its working for device however it is not playing sound. It is just displaying images after extraction. Any help for playing video??

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its not quite perfect yet , but we are actively developing it.

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/RtspFrames-test

Comment: I am getting 21 errors after dowloading and building it.. it gives error of  **"_avcodec_register_all", referenced from:
      -[FrameExtractor initWithVideo:] in FFmpegDecoder(FrameExtractor.o)** kind

Comment: should I have to set some linker flag or header search path or framework search path etc??

Answer (score 0):

What you downloaded is the frameExtractor , you can download rtspplay which is a full player based on ffplay, it does use SDL however. FFPlayer-tests , still extracts frames but can write a video only h264 movie.

right now that is the extent of our open source offerings. But we are working on some based on our commercial offerings. Which all include audio, most are open gl.

I'm sure we can work out something if you'd like to join our Facebook group were you can get more info , please visit our services site at wwww.mooncatbastet.com, for details.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have command line tools installed for OSX. Assuming you have Xcode, follow these instructions: [Xcode 4.4 and later install Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329243/xcode-4-4-and-later-install-command-line-tools)

Then you should be able to build live555 with:

./genMakefiles iphoneos

Note that depending on your version of osx you may need to change where Live555's Makefile is looking for the arm/build tools.